# No signature of method

Tags: groovy

I tried use this method on my control, but it always shows this message:

> No signature of method: br.com.owse.labs.owsetime.services.AcessoService.buscar() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [22/01/2014 00:00:00] Possible solutions: buscar(java.util.Date), listar(), editar(br.com.owse.labs.owsetime.domain.Acesso), salvar(br.com.owse.labs.owsetime.domain.Acesso), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)

This is my control method:

```
    @RequestMapping("/data/{data}")
String buscar(@PathVariable String data, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute 'dataBuscar', data

     String date = data
     String newDate = Date.parse( 'dd-MM-yyyy', date ).format( 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' )


    model.addAttribute 'acessos', acessoService.buscar(newDate)

    'acesso/acesso.index'
}
```

And the implementation:

```
@Override
public buscar(Date horaEntrada) {

    return hibernateDao.buscarPorCampo(Acesso, "horaEntrada", horaEntrada)
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a Date, not a String:

```
@RequestMapping("/data/{data}")
String buscar(@PathVariable String data, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute 'dataBuscar', data
    Date newDate = Date.parse( 'dd-MM-yyyy', data )
    model.addAttribute 'acessos', acessoService.buscar(newDate)
    'acesso/acesso.index'
}
```

Comment: I know, but I don't know How to it! I thought it would solve my problem using Date.parse!